# Using If statement to call a functions in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, boto3

I am running a code to create cloudformation stack, delete stack, update stack with defined parameter variable using json file using python.

I have defined a 3 different statement under init() function. I need to put a if condition: 
if i want to create a stack, it will call "create_products" 
else, update a stack, it will call "update_products"
elif, delete a stack, it will update "delete_products"

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import json
import yaml
import sys
import os
import re
import boto3
from glob import glob

def createstack(productName, productId, paramlist): 
    try:
        client = boto3.client('servicecatalog', region_name='us-east-1')
        ProvisioningArtifactId = client.list_provisioning_artifacts(ProductId=productId)
        ArtifactId = ProvisioningArtifactId['ProvisioningArtifactDetails'][0]['Id']
        response = client.provision_product(ProvisionedProductName=productName, ProductId=productId, ProvisioningArtifactId=ArtifactId, ProvisioningParameters=paramlist)
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        error = "An error occurred processing this request: " + str(e)
        print(error) 

def updatestack(productName, productId, paramlist):    
    try:
        client = boto3.client('servicecatalog', region_name='us-east-1')
        ProvisioningArtifactId = client.list_provisioning_artifacts(ProductId=productId)
        ArtifactId = ProvisioningArtifactId['ProvisioningArtifactDetails'][0]['Id']
        response = client.update_provisioned_product(ProvisionedProductName=productName, ProductId=productId, ProvisioningArtifactId=ArtifactId, ProvisioningParameters=paramlist)
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        error = "An error occurred processing this request: " + str(e)
        print(error)

def deletestack(productName):
    try:
        client = boto3.client('servicecatalog', region_name='us-east-1')
        response = client.terminate_provisioned_product(ProvisionedProductName=productName)
        print(response)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        error = "An error occurred processing this request: " + str(e)
        return(error)

def init():
    #global args
    with open("list_provisional_product.json") as f:
        product_list = json.load(f)
    with open("testing-pipeline-params.json") as f:
        baselist = json.load(f)

    for product in product_list["update_products"]:
        for provisioned_product_name in product["provisioned_product_names"]:
            updatestack(productName=provisioned_product_name, productId=product["product_id"], paramlist=baselist[provisioned_product_name])

    for product in product_list["delete_products"]:
        for provisioned_product_name in product["provisioned_product_names"]:
            deletestack(productName=provisioned_product_name)

    for product in product_list["create_products"]:
        for provisioned_product_name in product["provisioned_product_names"]:
            createstack(productName=provisioned_product_name, productId=product["product_id"], paramlist=baselist[provisioned_product_name])


def main():
    init()
if __name__== "__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to get operation name(Create/ Update/ Delete) from user via command line argument or ask user during code execution via `input` function.

**Demo 1**: Get Operation name from command line argument by using `sys.argv` 
You have to give operation name when you run your python code. Here Py file name is `if_loop.py`

```
import sys
print("arg:", sys.argv)

try:
    operation_name = sys.argv[1].lower()
except IndexError:
    print("Argument is missing")
    exit()

if operation_name == "create":
    print("Call Create function")
elif operation_name == "update":
    print("Call Update function")
elif operation_name == "delete":
    print("Call Dale function")
else:
    print("Invalid Operation name")
```

**Output**

```
Invalid Operation name
(env) PS C:\Users\vivek\Documents\Workplace\stackoverflow> python .\if_loop.py Create
arg: ['.\\if_loop.py', 'Create']
Call Create function
```

**Demo 2**: Using `input` function

```
operation_name = input("Give Operation Name:").lower()
if operation_name == "create":
    print("Call Create function")
elif operation_name == "update":
    print("Call Update function")
elif operation_name == "delete":
    print("Call Dale function")
else:
    print("Invalid Operation name")
```

**Output**

```
Give Operation Name:Update
Call Update function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Vivek ! I would rather go with approach 1st ie argv and it actually worked based on my need !! BRAVO